# SQL Entity Framework indexes through inheritance with include column option

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, indexing

I am coming today because of performances issues I have. I am now then working on Indexes, however, I can't find a proper way to put an index throughout classes inheritances.. I have this piece of code:

```
public abstract class BaseEntityWithId
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid Id { get; set; } = new Guid();

    [Required]
    public DateTimeOffset CreatedAt { get; set; } = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow;

    public DateTimeOffset? UpdatedAt { get; set; } = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow;
}

[Table("AccountExampleEntity")]
public class AccountExampleEntity : BaseEntityWithId
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    public string Password { get; set; }

    public Guid UserId { get; set; }

    public Guid DeviceId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public virtual UserEntity User { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("DeviceId")]
    public virtual DeviceEntity Device { get; set; }
}
```

From this code, Azure creates a warning and tells me the following:

- Index type

  - NONCLUSTERED
- Schema

  - [dbo]
- Table

  - [AccountExampleEntity]
- Index key columns

  - [UserId]
- Included columns

  - [CreatedAt], [DeviceId], [UpdatedAt]

So based on this, I want to create an index that I will share onto these 4 properties, however, I can't find the proper way to achieve it.. The only way I found was to recreate property by "hiding the inherited members". This is the code:

```
[Table("AccountExampleEntity")]
public class AccountExampleEntity : BaseEntityWithId
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Index("AccountExampleIndex", Order = 1)]
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }

    [Index("AccountExampleIndex", Order = 2)]
    public Guid DeviceId { get; set; }    

    [Index("AccountExampleIndex", Order = 3)]
    public new DateTimeOffset CreatedAt { get; set; } = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow;

    [Index("AccountExampleIndex", Order = 4)]
    public new DateTimeOffset? UpdatedAt { get; set; } = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow;

    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public virtual UserEntity User { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("DeviceId")]
    public virtual DeviceEntity Device { get; set; }
}
```

Is it the right way to do it or no? I couldn't find anything on stackoverflow and EF6 last time I checked, but today I am getting into it again and need to know :)

Thanks for help !